# Автоматическое проигрывание видео при загрузке страницы и ее оптимизация

Tags: javascript, html, видео

Для сайта требуется загрузка увесистого видео на первом экране. Видео хранится на том же домене, что и сайт, имеет autoplay. Использование хостингов (youtube, vimeo) недопустимо.

При заходе на страницу видео проигрывается не сразу.

Клиент хочет, чтобы видео проигрывалось моментально либо проигрывалось кусочками по мере загрузки. Это возможно? Если да, то как?

Как можно ускорить загрузку видео?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно преобразовать видео в формат OGV и подгружать, если у вас МП4 или AVI грузятся то я не знаю что будет с компом клиента особенно если открыта не 1 вкладка.